# DFS replication monitoring under a non-administrative account

Tags: windows-server-2012, monitoring, windows-server-2012-r2, dfs, dfs-r

I have a DFS replication set up on two Windows Server 2012 machines in a domain, the DFS consists of one namespace, two servers, several replication groups each containing one folder. I have been ordered to implement DFS-R monitoring via our local monitoring system. I want to collect backlog between those two servers in order to find out whether the DFS replication is stalled. The problem is, calling `dfsrdiag backlog` requires local administrator privileges on both servers, which is undesirable due to security reasons - the monitoring account should not have access to DFS contents. I have found some articles ([one](http://liveaverage.com/news/check_mk-dfs-backlog-monitoring/), [two](http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2006/07/06/440275.aspx)) regarding assignment of permissions to run `dfsrdiag backlog`, but after assigning all the permissions (DCOM users, root/microsoftdfs WMI permissions, DFS delegation on the groups) the actual run results in "Operation Failed". `dfsrdiag replicationstate` works, `dfsrdiag dumpmachinecfg` fails with a general access denied error (0x80041003).

What permissions does the account lack to perform successful queries against DFS?

EDIT: If running an elevated command prompt via "run as administrator - `runas /netonly /user:monitor cmd`" while the user is granted the listed permissions but not administrator rights, the `dfsrdiag dumpmachinecfg` command produces correct output, but `dfsr backlog` still says access denied.

Comment: Not sure if this would work, and Deny ACLs often create more problems than they solve... But you might try making the account a local admin, and then apply a Deny ACL to the filesystem data for that account.

Comment: @Craig620 It's difficult to do that, as changing ACLs initiates DFS replication of entire file set which ACLs got changed. There's just too much data on the DFS to tolerate desynch state for so long (~4 days estimated). On the other hand, we have established that if an administrative access would be requested from an admin account to a protected resource, the backlog will instantly rise and this will be noticed.